# Reason for use of mean value theorem in proof of Clairaut's Theorem

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I have been reading the proof of Clairaut's Theorem from Steward Calculus as shown:
[image: Clairaut's Theorem]

I am not able to figure out why the Mean Value Theorem (MVT) can be used here. From my limited knowledge, I think we require the function $g$ to be differentiable over the interval $(a,a+h)$ before we can use the MVT.

However I am not sure how the conditions "$f$ being defined on a disk $D$" as well as "$f_{xy}$ and $f_{yx}$ being both continuous on $D$" allow us to conclude the differentiability of $g$ over $(a,a+h)$.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How can $f_{xy}$ be defined without $f_x$ being defined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $f_{xy}$ exist on $D$, means that before you have $f_x$. (you need take derivative over something).

And for use MVT over $t \rightarrow f(t, y)$ only need the existence of $f_x$

Similar argument follow for $f_y$